# Formatar campo CPF ou CNPJ usando Regex

Tags: java, string, regex

Gostaria de uma expressão regular(REGEX) para formatar o campo de CPF ou CNPJ

Este é o codigo que cheguei até agora:

```
    String cpf ="09551130401";
    cpf = cpf.replaceAll("(\\d{2})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})(\\d{2})", "$1.$2.$3-$4");
    System.out.println(cpf);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**CNPJ:** (^\d{2}.\d{3}.\d{3}/\d{4}-\d{2}$)

**CPF:** (^\d{3}\x2E\d{3}\x2E\d{3}\x2D\d{2}$)

Usando Bean Validation, você pode definir um padrão para a sua variável.

```
@Pattern(regexp = "(^\d{3}\x2E\d{3}\x2E\d{3}\x2D\d{2}$)")
private String cpf;
```

Busquei estas expressões [aqui](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=CPF&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20)  e as testei neste [site](http://regexr.com).